# model value is not updating the UI of checkbox in vue.js laravel 5.8

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

**Below is my component in Vue.js and Laravel 5.8**

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            @change="validateBeforeSubmit()"
            v-model="accountSecurityForm.checked">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {        
        data() {
            return { 
                accountSecurityForm: {
                    checked: false
                }
            }
        },
        methods: {
            validateBeforeSubmit() {
                debugger;
                this.accountSecurityForm.checked = !this.accountSecurityForm.checked;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to set the value of checkbox on value change of checkbox.

My one line code is present in `method:validateBeforeSubmit`

But, that does not work, Am I missing anything?

**Update - 1**

I am able to get the correct true and false value on checked or unchecked correctly. But the model value is not updating the UI of checkbox

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code.The vue.js v-model automatically updates your checkbox data. In your case, the value is changing twice, once by v-model and second by "method:validateBeforeSubmit".

Chane your code to just this:

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        <input 
            type="checkbox"
            v-model="accountSecurityForm.checked">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {        
        data() {
            return { 
                accountSecurityForm: {
                    checked: false
                }
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per vue js docs you don't need to put a @change method for inputs. on input change its model will automatically triggered and updated. please remove @change="validateBeforeSubmit()"

```
<template>    
    <div class="container">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="accountSecurityForm.checked">
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {        
        data() {
            return { 
                accountSecurityForm: {
                    checked: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```